# SQL Sort by popularity?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can a sort by user popularity when using a hasAndBelongsToMany table relationship? ie:

I have a table called playgroups, players, and playgroup_players.

How can I sort playgroups by the number of players in the playgroup?

Playgroups:

```
CREATE TABLE `playgroups` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `tag` varchar(4) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `avatar_url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Players:

```
CREATE TABLE `players` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `public_email` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `facebook_id` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `card_tooltip` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `profile_pic_url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `public_name` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `city` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `date_joined` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=107 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

And PlaygroupPlayers:

```
CREATE TABLE `playgroup_players` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `player_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `playgroup_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `admin` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: A little moer information regarding tables might have helped. However u can have a look at the Group By Clause. 
select player group, count number of players
from tables
where clause
group by playerGroup
the result should have player group and corresponding count will represent number of players in that group

Comment: ok, i'll post the table structures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT PP.playgroup_id, COUNT(*) cnt
FROM playgroup_players PP
GROUP BY PP.playgroup_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

This will give you a list of playgroups that have at least one player sorted by the number of players. Of course, field name is made up  :)

```
SELECT G.playgroup_id, COUNT(PP.playgroup_id) cnt
FROM playgroup G
  LEFT OUTER JOIN playgroup_players PP ON (PP.playgroup_id=G.playgroup_id)
GROUP BY G.playgroup_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

This should give you a list of ALL playgroups (even the ones with no players). I've tested this on Oracle and on some of my own data and it works

Comment: I've altered second query, forgot LEFT JOIN. Try now

Comment: alright, that worked! thanks. now the fun part of using it in cakephp...:p

Comment: The JOIN is not needed. The GROUP BY was the thing missing.

Comment: You are correct, GROUP BY was missing from the first query (edited it)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT playgroups.*, d1.num_players
FROM playgroups
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT playgroup_id, count(*) as num_players 
    FROM playgroup_players 
    GROUP BY playgroup_id
) d1
ON playgroups.id = d1.playgroup_id
ORDER BY d1.num_players DESC
```

The inner query (a.k.a derived table) gives you the count for each playgroup.  The outer query joins that back to the main record in `playgroups`.  This form is required if you need to access non-aggregated columns in `playgroups`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this query should work.

```
SELECT pgp.playgroup_id, COUNT(pgp.id)
FROM playgroups_players pgp
GROUP BY pgp.playgroup_id
ORDER BY count(pgp.id)
```